# fetch data from web service to dataset in Delphi

Tags: web-services, delphi, dataset

i need to know about how to fetch data (array) from web service to my delphi dataset (db grid or string grid like REST Application),
give me an example please...
best regards

Comment: By coding, what have you tried?

Comment: How to retrieve data from the webservice is determine by the webservice. Then you parse the data and put it in a database.

Comment: I've try single result from web service (not in array or multiple record), but i need to fetch my data from web services containing a data from database.

Comment: this is my WSDL address http://net-combo.info/webservices/siakadws.php?wsdl

Comment: google gives a lot of results for "Delphi WSDL" , for example http://www.onlinedelphitraining.com/newsletters/webservices.htm for example http://deldev.blogspot.ru/2009/04/webservice.html for example http://rusdelphi.com/internet/poluchenie-kursa-valyut-centrobanka/ for example  http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/web_services.html and so on

Answer (score 0):

I use web services in Delphi 7(soap 1.1) and Rad Studio XE6(soap 1.2).  I recomend to use the WDSL Importer that comes with the IDE to make a .dcu file that represents the WebService(WS). Then you have to include the dcu file in the 'uses' of your .pas file.

Then, define the WS as a global static variable. You have to respect all the names in your dcu WS file.

So,

1- Use wdsl importer to create dcu file of the WS.

2- Include imported file in your 'uses' section.

3- Define the static var of the file.

4- Use the static var to call methods of the WS.

Hope it helps!
Bye